# how can I access folders outside the app private folder using QFileDialog on android in Qt 5.2.0rc1

Tags: android, qt5

I can only see the private directory of the app. I have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the *AndroidManifest.xml*. How do I get to see files on my device I want to open in my Qt app?

An example of this is using the *AudioRecorder* project from the *multimedia examples*.

Comment: which API/os are u using? if its 4.1 above take a look at this http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Permissions

Comment: That doesn't seem to add anything. As I said, I already request write access and it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: i think you have to use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to read data, if its 4.1 or above

Comment: I made the simplest possible app and this can see the whole storage with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and without READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but thanks for making me persevere. If I can reproduce this in my main app I'll write an answer for it. It is very strange